# In this situation, why is $h(x)=\int_0^1 f(x-y) g(y) dy$ negative?

Tags: calculus, integration, functional-analysis

$f : \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ be a continuous periodic function with period $1$.

Suppose there exists $a\in [0,1]$ s.t. $f(a)<0$.

Then, there exists $g\in C^\infty([0,1])$ s.t.
\begin{align}
&g(a)=1\\
&0\leqq g(x)\leqq 1 \ \mathrm{\ for \ } x\in [0,1]\\
&g(x)=0 \mathrm{\ on \ } [0,1]\setminus J \mathrm{\ where\ } J=\{ x\in [0,1]\mid f(x)<0 \}
\end{align}

(For example, the bump function works as $g$.)

Define $h:\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ by $h(x):=\int_0^1 f(x-y) g(y) dy$.

My book says this $h$ is negative, i.e., $h(x)<0$ for all $x\in [0,1]$, but I don't know why.

($h$ is periodic with period $1$ so $h<0$ for all $x\in [0,1]$ $\iff$ $h<0$ for all $x\in \mathbb R.$)

I have $h(x)=\int_J f(x-y) g(y) dy+ \int_{[0,1]\setminus J}\ \ f(x-y) g(y) dy=\int_J f(x-y) g(y) dy$ since $g=0$ on $[0,1]\setminus J.$

So what I have to show is $\int_J f(x-y) g(y) dy<0.$

On $J$, $f(x)$ is negative but I don't know whether the integrand  $f(x-y)$ is negative, and even if $f(x-y)$ is negative, $g$ satisfies $g\geqq 0$ so I can only say $\int_J f(x-y) g(y) dy\leqq 0.$

I'm stacked here.

Could you explain the reason why we can say $h$ is negative ?

(I didn't use $g(a)=1$ yet. The condition $g(a)=1$ may be useful.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The statement $h<0$ is false, consider $f(y)=-\sin(2\pi y)$ then $f(1-y)=-f(y)$.

Let $a=1/4$ and let $g(y)$ be a symmetrical bump on $[0,1/2]$, centred at $y=1/4$, with $g(1/4)=1$.

You can check all conditions for $f$ and $g$ are satisfied.

Then $h(1)=\int_0^1f(1-y)g(y)dy=-\int_0^1f(y)g(y)dy\geq0$ since $f(y)g(y)\leq0$ for all $y\in[0,1]$.

Comment: So, the statement $h<0$ for all $x$ in my book may be false. My book says [$h<0$ for all $x$] in order to show that [$h\geqq 0$ for all $x$] doesn't hold. But in order to show that [$h\geqq 0$ for all $x$] doesn't hold, it sufficies to show there **exists** $x_0$ s.t. $h(x_0)<0$. Is there such $x_0$ ? $x_0=a$ works ?

Comment: @inc In the above example, you could check that $x_0=1/2$ is such a point. Indeed, since $f(1/2-x)=f(x)$ we have $h(1/2)=\int_0^1f(1/2-x)g(x)=\int_0^1f(x)g(x)<0$.